# Less Mixins for Grid Class No Longer Supported in Bootstrap 3.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Seems that in Bootstrap 3.2, LESS no longer supports mixins defined as `.col-@{class}-@{index}`, such that this code will fail due to `.col-xs-12`:

```
@import 'twitter/bootstrap';
.test {
  .text-center;
  .text-uppercase;
  .col-xs-12;
}
```

My entire site uses this method; are there any work-arounds without having to rewrite all my stylesheets?

Comment: "No longer supported" implies that this worked at some point previously; I'm pretty sure it never has.

Comment: it absolutely does.  I rolled back to the less-rails-bootstrap 3.0.2 (which uses an earlier version of twbootstrap, because I didn't want to re-write all my stylesheets) and it's working as we speak.  I probably won't upgrade that gem until Bootstrap v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here in a similar issue addressed in the twitter/bootstrap repo: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14314

and the related solution below:

```
@import 'twitter/bootstrap';
.test {
  .text-center;
  .text-uppercase;
  .make-xs-column(12);
}
```

according to that same thread, this may change for bootstrap v4 (which is a real pain).